# AngularJS $q: How to chain promises then do parallel last in the chain?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

I am trying to chain series of tasks, that returns a promise, the do parallel execution at the last of the chain. The code below doesn't work, I thought you can pass any object that returns a promise inside "then". Is there a proper way of implementing this. Thank you.

```
var startTask = $q.when (  );

startTasks
   .then ( validate )
   .then ( savePayment )
   .then ( refetchPayment )
   .then ( saveContactInfo )
   .then ( $q.all ( [ updateStatus, submitOrder ] ) )
   .then ( successHandler )
   .catch ( errorHandler );
```

Comment: A very good article here : http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, `$q.all( [ updateStatus, submitOrder] )` always returns an immediately resolved promise.

What you want to do is probably something like this (guessing)

```
.then(function(response) {
    return $q.all( [ updateStatus(response), submitOrder(response) ] );
 });
```

See the difference?

`[updateStatus,submitOrder]` is just an array of function references, calling `$q.all` on an array of things that aren't promises will always return an immediately resolved promise.

You need to **call** those functions, as (I'm assuming) those functions return `promises` when called.

`$q.all` takes an array of promises and returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises passed into it are resolved.

Comment: Yes, those functions returns promises. I tried   `.then ( $q.all ( [ updateStatus (  ), submitOrder (  ) ] ) )` but it doesn't work too. I guess I really need to wrap the $q.all call in a function. Thank you for the quick response, really appreciate it.